# Return Value of File Based Write Filter via Batchfile

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command, errorlevel

i try to get a return value of the fbwfmgr.exe inside a batchfile.
I have already read many articles about programming with it's API,
but i need the batchfile.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You seem to be looking for `%errorlevel%`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
start "" "fbwfmgr.exe"  [some options]
if %errorlevel% neq 0 echo FAIL!
```

Comment: Okay, this ist perfect if you enabling the FBWF. But how can I get the status of the FBWF? If I execute fbwfmgr.exe than I get a text message. I do not want to compare this string..

Comment: If you are not looking for %ERRORLEVEL% (which is the return code from fbwfmgr.exe) and you do not want to compare the string that is output from the process, what exactly are you expecting to do?

Comment: You have already solved my primary problem. Now I want to know how I can check in a batch file that the fbwf is enabled (after the reboot of the system). It is possible to check it via the return text. But it is cleaner to check it via a return value like 0 or 1.

Sorry for my question, it was the first time for me.

Comment: Please make a new question, it's quite easy. [click me!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)